# Radix sort's linear run time

Tags: algorithms, sorting, analysis-of-algorithms

We know that radix sort's run time is $\Theta (d(n +k))$ where n is the no. of elements to be sorted, k is the range of individual digit of the elements ($k =O(n)$) and $d$ is the no. of digits in every element, which is assumed to be constant.
I am wondering that if we re-arrange any random list of elements to contain same constant no. of digits we will be able to achieve a $\Theta(n)$ time.

For eg.
5, 72, 99, 343, 2, 8999, 1765, 57, 554, 12

can be rearranged to

0005, 0072, 0099, 0343, 0002, 8999, 1765, 0057, 0554, 0012

now, here $d = 4$ (constant) and also $k= O(n)$ (0 to 9)

We can do this with any random arrangement of numbers and achieve a linear time,
Where am I wrong $?$

Comment: You need to go through what constant mean in this context. It means constant as the input changes, not when you iterate the elements of the input.

Comment: If you have at least $n$ distinct elements, one of them must have at least $\log n$ digits. In which case the run time is $\Omega(n \log n)$ as expected. On the other hand, if you hold $d$ fixed and let $n$ go to $\infty$, you can indeed sort your list in linear time, but most of the numbers in it will eventually be duplicates of each other, so it's unsurprising that you don't have to work at sorting them!

Comment: @Micah You have nailed the issue (I think you should make it an answer). A tangential comment: if you have $n$ numbers each of length $\log n$, then the size of the input is $n \log n$, so the algorithm sorting such an input is actually linear (in size of the input) despite having complexity $\Theta(n \log n)$ in terms of $n$ (i.e., it is _not_ linear in $n$).